# Assign an array to a key which is a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array (Ruby on Rails) like:

```
[{"name"=>"Start Time", "id"=>3, "value"=>"15:00"}, 
 {"name"=>"End Time",   "id"=>4, "value"=>"16:00"}]
```

How can I assign this array to a key so that it looks like:

```
{"custom_fields": [{"name"=>"Start Time", "id"=>3, "value"=>"15:00"}, 
                   {"name"=>"End Time",   "id"=>4, "value"=>"16:00"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

correct syntax for a ruby [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) litteral is :

```
hash = { "string key" => value }
hash = { :symbol_key  => value }
```

this syntax is only available for ruby > 1.9 and for hashes that only have [symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) as keys :

```
hash = { symbol_key: value }
```

ps: you should probably delve into a good ruby book to learn the basics. A recognized reference among rubyist is the ["pickaxe"](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby) book

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close.  Like another user said you'll need to use the old syntax `=>` if your hash key is a string.

```
{"custom_fields" => [{"name"=>"Start Time", "id"=>3, "value"=>"15:00"}, 
                   {"name"=>"End Time",   "id"=>4, "value"=>"16:00"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know ruby on rails, but my guess from looking at what you wrote would be:

```
[{"custom_fields"=>{{"name"=>"Start Time", "id"=>3, "value"=>"15:00"}, {"name"=>"End Time", "id"=>4, "value"=>"16:00"}}}]
```

Comment: no. i want to make it a key value pair with an additional string as the key and an existing array as the value

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new hash and assign your array to the key `custom_fields`:

```
myHash = Hash.new
myHash['custom_fields'] = myArray
```

Also, I recommend you reading about hashes and arrays ; they aren't the same thing in Ruby.
If you come from a PHP background for example, you can pretend that a hash is an associative array, and an array is... an array that doesn't have keys (for example `[:a, :b, :c]`).